# Receiving an empty output from the GPS device to store the value in SQL DB using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
class Program
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                IPAddress hostIPAddress1 = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                tcpClient.Connect(hostIPAddress1, xxx);

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                        StringBuilder b1;

                        if (networkStream.CanRead)
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

                            byte[] Latitude = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            string dataReceivedLatitude = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Latitude, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received Latitude : " + dataReceivedLatitude);

                            byte[] Longitude = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            string dataReceivedLongitude = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Longitude, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received Longitude : " + dataReceivedLongitude);

                            byte[] Date = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            string dataReceivedDate = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Date, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received Date : " + dataReceivedDate);

                            byte[] Time = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            string dataReceivedTime = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Time, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received Time : " + dataReceivedTime);

        byte[] Speed = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            string dataReceivedSpeed = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Speed, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received Speed : " + dataReceivedSpeed);

                            byte[] IMEI = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            string dataReceivedIMEI = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(IMEI, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            Console.WriteLine("Received IMEI : " + dataReceivedIMEI);
    [enter image description here][1]                            
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: Remote client disconnected. " + ex.ToString());
                        tcpClient.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Print("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
                        tcpClient.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return;
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

the above code is i have written it for retrieving the GPS device value but i have received like \0\0\0\0 so on, i have configured the device already, but again i have reset it , still receiving the same error output and can any one please help me how to retrieve the value.

Comment: is your GPS device is sending data to you on specific IP?

Comment: no it is not sending.

Comment: @MihirDave can u help me...

Comment: I can try, but I am having a hard time understanding your issue because normally GPS devices send data to the server, but I am guessing you have TcpServer running server and that is sending GPS Data so seeing that code and elaborating your situation can help

Comment: @MihirDave Since I'm new to this technology the above code which i have written is for connecting device using network stream layer, so for reading the value i have declared the ipaddress and  tcpclient for connection. this one is i have read it from microsoft, also the device if i give a call it sending message value like lat,long,imei,date,speed. But after configuring the same ip and port with device and in my c# code  i receive the output as \0\0\0\\0\0(an empty value).

Comment: Again I don't see anything related to server here, e.g. code on server side which receives data from GPS device and code which answers when make request with tcp client, I can't help with half the information missing ->architecture,code on server

Comment: @MihirDave sorry, i just thought after connecting with TCP client and network stream by assigning the ip and port value, the gps will started sending the signal and we can receive and store it. can you please share me any sample code regarding a complete cycle for receiving and storing the value from the GPS device to SQL server.

Comment: this will take more than a sample code, it is an architecture for product you are talking about there so many things to understand and so many pieces to joint together. simple answer on SO won't suffice.

Comment: @MihirDave can you please share me your mail ID, so that i can send the information regarding what i have done for retrieving the values and storing it in SQL server.